# Handling users of phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, security, phpmyadmin, privileges

Hi stackoverflow community,

I have some doubts in how to manage the users in phpMyAdmin, I am starting a project but I see multiple users with **ALL PRIVILEGES**.

1. I should choose one user, set my password, and then delete the other ones?
2. Having multiple users with **ALL PRIVILEGES** and without any password can be a **security trouble**?
3. What is the difference between the **root** users? And servers **127.0.0.1**, **::1** and **localhost**?

I leave here an image to be more specific and show graphically what I meaning.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7WuU.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVFW7.jpg

I would appreciate detailed and understandable answers.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL allows you to restrict permissions to a username, host pair. This means that the user only has the permissions when they login from the specified host. Typically you restrict MySQL admin permissions only if the user on the local machine (ie: the one that is running MySQL). The local machine can be called `localhost`, `127.0.0.0`, or, in IPv6, `::1`. So you only have one root user. They will only be given admin privileges when they login from the local host. You shouldn't delete any of them. You should set the password on the `::1` line (I don't know why it's not set).

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I set the passwords for 127.0.0.1 and localhost root users but I didn't set for ::1, in default, all root users comes without password.